# python program does not stop

Tags: python, pyqt

I tried to design a pyqt gui in which when I press start it initiates the function fun1 and start printing "HI" after every 3 seconds . And what I intended that when I press quit, gui should be closed and program has to be stopped.But it is still printing "HI" I am using spyder windows 7 python 3.6

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def fun1(self):
        import time
        for i in range(10000):
            print("HI")
            time.sleep(3)
    def fun2(self):
        import sys
        self.hide()
        quit()
        print("..")

    def launch_thread(self):
        import threading
        x=threading.Thread(target=self.fun1)
        x.start()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))        
        self.layout=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btn1=QtWidgets.QPushButton("start",self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.launch_thread)
        self.btn2=QtWidgets.QPushButton("quit",self)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.fun2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn2,0,1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It will keep running and keep printing until `fun1()` completes. Which is going to be after about 30000 seconds. So you should probably design your program differently.

Comment: is there no way to stop fun1()

Comment: Sure, there are ways to stop `fun1()` but why do you have fun1 in the first place? What is the problem you're actually trying to solve? It's probably not 'print HI 30000 thousand times'. So describe that in your question.

Comment: basically my fun1 contains a selenium script that is automating some form filling.But in case any error occured the user have to just press quit to stop the script

Comment: If you have a member variable `self.running` that you can set/check you can set that to false in `fun2` and to true in `fun1` at the beginning and you can check to see if it's still true as the after each iteration. You can probably also use interrupts and joins in some combination more effectively though

Comment: what if function fun1 has no iterations inside.Cant I stop a running function?For e.g. I do browser.get("url") and url is temporarily down and further script is attached by finding elements by id,class etc.  But since I am able to see the url is down I have to stop the process then and there

Comment: You should edit your question and add these details.

Comment: @NimishBansal. If `fun1` cannot be interrupted, there is no way to force it to stop. The only solution is to use a separate *process*, rather than a thread: i.e. use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro thats too big.Should I invest time in reading the complete documentation?

Comment: @NimishBansal. No - just use your favourite search engine to look for a basic tutorial. Random example: [Multiprocessing Basics](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/basics.html).

Comment: I added a new question .Can you help there.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144412/pyqt-how-to-connect-stop-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fun1_flag = False
        self.initUI()

    def fun1(self):
        import time
        self.fun1_flag = False
        for i in range(10000):
            print("HI")
            time.sleep(3)
            if self.fun1_flag:
                return
    def fun2(self):
        import sys
        self.fun1_flag = True
        self.hide()
        quit()
        print("..")

    def launch_thread(self):
        import threading
        x=threading.Thread(target=self.fun1)
        x.start()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))        
        self.layout=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btn1=QtWidgets.QPushButton("start",self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.launch_thread)
        self.btn2=QtWidgets.QPushButton("quit",self)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.fun2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn2,0,1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```