# pyqt how to connect stop button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I tried to design a pyqt gui in which when I press start it initiates the function fun1 and that starts selenium script in funbrowser. And what I intended that when I press "stop", the function funbrowser stops running regardless of where is the control in funbrowser. and also pyqt window  should be closed and program has to be stopped.But it is still printing "HI" I am using spyder windows 7 python 3.6
So what should I connect to button stop so that funbrowser stops.

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def funbrowser(self,browser,details):
        browser.get("https://fileml.com/l/0w5O")
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.switch_to.frame("offer-iframe")
        elemlist=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul/li/a")
        list_of_names=[] #All those present
        for i in range(len(elemlist)):
            list_of_names.append(str(elemlist[i].text))
        print("\n")
        print(list_of_names)
        lon=len(list_of_names)*[0]
        available=[] #All those linked
        for i in range(len(elemlist)):
            if "Register for Free" in elemlist[i].text:
                lon[i]="register"
                available.append("register")
            if "Health Samples" in elemlist[i].text:
                lon[i]="health"
                available.append("health")
        print("Available",available)
        print("lon",lon)
        selected=random.choice(available)
        print("selected is ",selected)

        clickon=lon.index(selected)
        print(clickon)
        elemlist[clickon].click()
        alert = browser.switch_to.alert
        alert.accept()    

    def fun1(self):
        browser=webdriver.Firefox()
        self.funbrowser(browser,details)

    def fun2(self):
        import sys
        self.hide()
        quit()
        print("..")

    def launch_thread(self):
        import threading
        x=threading.Thread(target=self.fun1)
        x.start()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))        
        self.layout=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btn1=QtWidgets.QPushButton("start",self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.launch_thread)
        self.btn2=QtWidgets.QPushButton("stop",self)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect()
        self.btn3=QtWidgets.QPushButton("quit",self)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn2,0,1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn3,0,2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()
```

What function should I have to connec to self.btn2("stop")

Comment: self.btn2.clicked.connect() - connect it to function

Comment: ya  but what should be the content of the function?I want to know that only

Comment: what is expected result? stop thread with self.fun1 and close app?

Comment: yes self.fun1 should be stopped and pyqt window should be just like a new fresh window just like running for the first time

Comment: First of all make `browser=webdriver.Firefox()` as field of the class. Than, create function like `close_web_driver` and connect it to the button. At that function call method `self.browser.stop_client()`.

Comment: oh thanks got your point

Comment: amm any upvotes ?  I lost my previlege to ask questions :(